# Stack inline-block divs and keep it responsive

Tags: css, html, responsive-design

I'm not so sure of where I would be looking to know what way i should do this and I feel like there would be multiple choices.

So I'm trying to align divs that are set to inline-block so they flow like text, and that jump down (be responsive) when the screen size get smaller. Also, it has to be done only with CSS styling.

They have to look like this (the spacing between the divs aren't a concern here):
[image]

My code looks like this (the `#item_*`s contains images and text to set their size):

```
<div id="main_wrapper">
    <div id="content_wrapper">
        <div id="content">
            <div id="item_container">
                <div id="item"></div>
                <div id="item"></div>
                <div id="item"></div>
                <div id="item"></div>
                <div id="item"></div>
                <div id="item"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And my style look like this:

```
#main_wrapper{
    overflow: auto;
}

#content_wrapper{
    max-width: none;
    margin: 64px 194px;
    margin-right: 26px;
}

#content{
    padding:28px 33px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    overflow: auto;
}

#item_container{
    text-align: center;
}

#item{
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
}

#content_wrapper{
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.85);
    max-width: 462px;
    font-family: "Courier New", Courier, monospace;
}
```

Comment: you could use bootstrap http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-example-basic

Comment: Why can't you just float them? And the code you gave doesn't help us reproduce your layout, [the elements have no width/height](http://jsfiddle.net/4d7PV/)

Comment: should I just put the whole thing I'm working on on a free webhost?